# Sockets over the net

Tags: java, sockets

I am implementing a Socket program in Java and realized that Socket and ServerSocket classes can only be used in my LocalNetwork.What i need to do,so that a remote PC(different router)  can connect to my PC(server)?what API should i use?

Comment: They can only be used in ways your network allows.  You cannot pass through a firewall which prevents this.  Also you cannot use it to connect to networks you have no access to. If you cannot connect this way, it is a network issue.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing about `Socket` and `ServerSocket` that limits them to the local network. There may be issues around firewalls and such, but the classes themselves won't place any additional constraints.

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction, It can be used over the internet as well, Ideally what you want to do is to make sure your firewall permits you to connect to the port listened by the socket, you can create a port forwarding via your DMZ or NAT to filter and forward requests to the listening machine.

Answer (score 1):

> "Socket and ServerSocket classes can only be used in my LocalNetwork."

Where did you get that from?

Anyway, the Socket and ServerSocket are not restricted to local network at all. This is not local:

```
Socket s = new Socket("www.java2s.com", 80);
```

However, if your client and server are on different networks, then you have to set up the proper routing (i.e. configure the router's DMZ, etc.).